# Adobe Illustrator, is it possible to place one artboard on another in the same file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

I'm wondering if it would be possible to take one artboard and place copies of it on other art boards that would update automatically.

One use example is a sheet of mailing labels.

I do this currently by placing the .ai file and selecting the page I want.

The problem with this is that every time I save I have to save twice and also update the links referencing the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon the artwork, **Symbols** may be what you are seeking.

If you create one Symbol, you can then place **symbol instances** (duplicates) as often as you want. Editing the Symbol will result in *all* referenced symbol instances being updated.

To create a symbol, simply select your artwork and drag it to the **Symbol Panel**.

To place instances, simply copy the symbol on your artboard and duplicate it somewhere else. You can also drag from the **Symbol Panel** to any artboard and it will "drop" an instance of that Symbol.

To edit a Symbol, simply double-click it in the Symbol Panel.

Referring to artboards, yes You can stack artboards on top of one another, overlap them, or anything you need. However, layers are not *directly* associated with artboards. So you have to watch for overlapping artwork if you wish to have separate art on the various (overlapping) artboards.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the information I was looking for.

I knew there had to be some way to do this.